# Ink! chrono DateTime

Tags: ink, substrate-contracts-node

I'm trying to use `chrono` crate from [substrate chrono docs](https://docs.substrate.io/rustdocs/latest/chrono/struct.DateTime.html#) when implementing a ink! smart contract.

I've just imported `chrono::DateTime` and `chrono::Utc` from the crate and can compile and run test.

However I get errors when trying to build the contract with `cargo +nightly contract build`:

`doesn't have a size known at compile-time`

Do you know what I'm missing? Is there a better/standard way to handle dates and timestamps?

Comment: Can you please add the line of your `Cargo.toml` where you import the crate to your question?

Comment: I found that changing from `chrono = "0.4"` to `chrono = { version = "0.4", default-features = false }` solved the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changing from

```
[dependencies]
chrono = "0.4"
```

to

```
[dependencies]
chrono = { version = "0.4", default-features = false }
```

in Cargo.toml solved the issue

Comment: You can accept your own answer.